# SASS/CSS to place N items into a sidebar

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a controller, which will allow for the configuration of multiple items to go into a sidebar. The sidebar CSS looks like this:

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: $bigZIndex;
}
```

Because there is a config to make each individual sidebar component, there is an arbitrary order and number of them. Regardless, I would want them to be placed in the same manner each and every time. Eg, start at `top: 25%` and position everything below that in order with a small margin between each. For reference, a config would look something like this:

```
{
  id: thing1Id,
  controller: thing1Controller
}, {
  id: thing2Id,
  controller: thing2Controller
}
```

However, it could also look like this:

```
{
  id: thing2Id,
  controller: thing2Controller
}, {
  id: aRandomThing,
  controller: madnessController
}
```

Ideally, it should be generic enough to handle any of these situations. How would something like this be done?

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like it might just call for: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp. Or you could programmatically assign classes to each 'thing' in Javascript to help, or if you use something like knockout/angular for data-binding and the 'things' are in a collection you could use access the index.

Comment: previously, I was doing a calc() of the top and saving it as a variable. It just feels like there MUST be a better way

Comment: you should look at flex-box: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and the order property- http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: I don't see what the problem here is or why you think Sass can solve it for you.

Comment: the only problem is I support ie9